# Select 9 AM on the 1st of current month

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to schedule a job that will run at 9 AM of the 1st of the current month.
So I want a query  that will select this day and time

```
10/1/0020 9:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Do you like to create a **job** which runs at 09:00 on the 1st of current month or do you need a query which selects this time? Note, 2020-10-01 already passed by, so if you like to create a job, then this job will run at `2020-11-01 09:00:00` the first time.

Comment: I don't understand why you "need a query" in order to schedule a job.  If you know what time you want the job to run (9;00 am, first day of the month), just set it up to run at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `trunc()` to get the first of the month, then add 9 hours:

```
trunc(sysdate, 'month') + interval '9' hour
```